# Ceiling drywall for garage and fire code?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, code-compliance, garage

In a multi-unit town home (single building) there is a 3-bay garage.

Is there a building code, or fire code, that requires the ceiling to be fully drywalled?

Is it allowable to remove ceiling drywall and leave sections removed, either indefinitely or up to some period of time?  It would be for access to plumbing and for keeping an eye out for leaks. Such as a 2 foot square a 16" wide by couple feet long where drain pipe elbows would be?  And if for example a small section was removed is it acceptable/compliant to use a piece of plywood with screws that can be dropped conveniently anytime in the future?  It is a garage so there is no need to make it look nice.

Is there a specific type of drywall needed for the ceiling in the garage area to meet building/fire code?  And to what extent does its installation need to be in regards to taping and mudding and visual appearance?

This is in CT.

Comment: Depends on what's behind the ceiling and adjacent walls. There's not enough detail here to answer.

Comment: Codes aside, Drywall on the ceiling and walls helps to buy you enough time to escape a car fire, and perhaps save the structure. Especially so if rooms above.

Comment: You can always remove drywall for repairs. There are too many questions included here. You should edit this down to one question that can be answered with factual information.

Answer (score 5):

Codes vary by location. The best solution would be to go to your local building department and ask them what you need to do. In the end they are the ones that will issue a permit if required and pass the project when finished.

Comment: this does not answer any of my question

Comment: Actually, this is the _best_ answer you'll get. You've been rather vague about the structure and few of us will know your local codes. National codes are adopted by local jurisdictions (or not) and are not universally applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a townhome there should be codes and rules in place that require each garage to be "sealed" from the other. This is usually a minimum of 5/8 drywall on the ceiling and drywall closing any attic space so it is not open to the adjacent unit. Most areas have code that require the seams to be taped and mudded.  Looks are of no concern.

That said, if you have an area open for the purpose of inspection and observance one may say that is allowed, but the timeframe may be dictated by any community association, or what might be assumed as a "reasonable" amount of time.
A few days is probably ok.  A week may be pushing it.  Months and you are the "problem" neighbor. Just leave it open and you are not only risking your garage and home but the others too.  Don't be "that guy"

Replacing the drywall with plywood?  The plywood is not fire rated, so no, not a good idea and your insurance may not stay in effect.
You can make a drywall access port, with trim or 1x frame around the drywall,  and not be "That guy".

Comment: it's one big open 3 bay garage, with lally columns between each bay, that's how the place was built (back in the 80's I think)  "Townhome" may be an inaccurate description - condo I guess... 3 unit single 1 floor living space on top of semi-below ground foundation.  Unit's #1, #2, #3; unit #1 about 800 sqft is entirely over 3-bay garage; each unit has their own front & back door to outside.

Comment: If a condo and living unit above it is imperative that you do not compromise the fire blocking.  The condo association has rules on this type of thing too.

Answer (score 3):

### Drywall is an essential part of that fire separation

Assuming that that is a frame floor-ceiling atop your garage (vs. a solid slab of concrete), that floor-ceiling is required to at least have a 5/8" Type X drywall fire barrier protecting it and the unit above it from a fire in the garage, with 1/2" drywall protecting the supports. See IBC 406.3.2.1 for the details in this case.